# How Automatically Update Two or Several GtkDrawAreas in C

Tags: c, gtk

I'm trying to develop a little Supervision System with two GtkDrawarea Widgets and update them simultaneously whenever I toogle the buttons regarded for each Drawarea. A little example I made for ploting two sinoides.

However just the first GtkDrawarea Widget are updated in did, the other remains freezed until I rezise the GtkWindow. I tried use g_timeout_add_full but I seens to work only with one GtkDrawArea.

I'm sending an image of my test aplication.

If someone could help me I will be very thankful.

PS: Sorry for my English :-)

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <cairo.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

GtkWidget       *window;

GtkWidget       *darea1;
GtkWidget       *darea2;

double w_larg = 1600;
double w_alt  = 1200;

bool toggle_stat1 = false;
bool toggle_stat2 = false;

int width, height;

double fase1 = 2;
double amp1  = 1.25;

double fase2 = 4;
double amp2  = 1.25;

gboolean flag_amp1 = TRUE;
gboolean flag_amp2 = TRUE;

static gboolean invalidate_drawing1(gpointer data);
static gboolean invalidate_drawing2(gpointer data);
//*******************************************************************************

static gboolean  on_toggled1(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
if(gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(widget)))
    {toggle_stat1 = true;
    printf("ToggleButton01 --> Acionado / toggle_stat1 = %d\n",toggle_stat1);
        g_timeout_add_full(G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE,250,invalidate_drawing1,darea1,NULL);  // Variação atualizada da linha acima :-)
    }
else
    {toggle_stat1 = false;
    printf("ToggleButton01 --> Liberado / toggle_stat1 = %d\n",toggle_stat1);
    }
return FALSE;
}
//*******************************************************************************

static gboolean  on_toggled2(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
if(gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(widget)))
    {toggle_stat2 = true;
    printf("ToggleButton02 --> Acionado / toggle_stat2 = %d\n",toggle_stat2);
          g_timeout_add_full(G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE,250,invalidate_drawing2,darea2,NULL);  // Variação atualizada da linha acima :-)
    }
else
    {toggle_stat2 = false;
    printf("ToggleButton02 --> Liberado / toggle_stat2 = %d\n",toggle_stat2);
    }
return FALSE;
}
//*******************************************************************************
//*******************************************************************************
//*******************************************************************************
//*******************************************************************************
static gboolean draw_darea1(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
int     valor1;
double  valor2;

static const double dashed1[] = {4.0, 21.0, 2.0};
static const double dashed3[] = {2.0};

cr = gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window(widget));
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 1);
cairo_rectangle(cr,0 , 0, widget->allocation.width, widget->allocation.height);
cairo_fill(cr);

double i = widget->allocation.width;
double j = widget->allocation.height;
double sc = fase1*M_PI/i;
double y;
double h = 0;
if (amp1 != 0) h = h + j/amp1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0, 0, 1, 1);
cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1.5);

cairo_move_to(cr, 0, (j/2)+(sin( (-i/2)*sc   )*(h/2))  );
for(double x=(-i/2);x<=(i/2);x=x+2)
{
valor1 = rand()%5;
valor2 = rand()%50;
y=x*sc;
if (valor1 < 3 ) cairo_line_to(cr,x+(i/2),(j/2)+(sin(y)*(h/2)) + valor2 );
if (valor1 == 3) cairo_line_to(cr,x+(i/2),(j/2)+(sin(y)*(h/2))          );
if (valor1 > 3 ) cairo_line_to(cr,x+(i/2),(j/2)+(sin(y)*(h/2)) - valor2 );

}
cairo_stroke(cr);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 1, 1, 0, 1);
cairo_set_dash(cr,dashed1, 1, 0 );
cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1.5);

cairo_move_to(cr, 0, (j/2)+(sin( (-i/2)*sc   )*(h/2))  );
for(double x=(-i/2);x<=(i/2);x=x+10)
{
y=x*sc;
cairo_line_to(cr,x+(i/2),(j/2)+(sin(y)*(h/2))       );
}
cairo_stroke(cr);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
cairo_set_dash(cr,dashed3, 1, 0 );
cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1.0);
cairo_move_to(cr,0,(j/2));
cairo_line_to(cr,i,(j/2));
cairo_move_to(cr,(i/2),0);
cairo_line_to(cr,(i/2),j);
cairo_stroke(cr);

cairo_destroy(cr);
return TRUE;
}
//*******************************************************************************
//*******************************************************************************
//*******************************************************************************
//*******************************************************************************

static gboolean draw_darea2(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
int     valor1;
double  valor2;

static const double dashed1[] = {4.0, 21.0, 2.0};
static const double dashed3[] = {2.0};

cr = gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window(widget));
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 1);
cairo_rectangle(cr,0 , 0, widget->allocation.width, widget->allocation.height);
cairo_fill(cr);

double i = widget->allocation.width;
double j = widget->allocation.height;
double sc = fase2*M_PI/i;
double y;
double h = 0;
if (amp2 != 0) h = h + j/amp2;
//---------------------
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0, 0, 1, 1);
cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1.5);

cairo_move_to(cr, 0, (j/2)+(sin( (-i/2)*sc   )*(h/2))  );
for(double x=(-i/2);x<=(i/2);x=x+2)
{
valor1 = rand()%5;
valor2 = rand()%50;
y=x*sc;
if (valor1 < 3 ) cairo_line_to(cr,x+(i/2),(j/2)+(sin(y)*(h/2)) + valor2 );
if (valor1 == 3) cairo_line_to(cr,x+(i/2),(j/2)+(sin(y)*(h/2))          );
if (valor1 > 3 ) cairo_line_to(cr,x+(i/2),(j/2)+(sin(y)*(h/2)) - valor2 );

}
cairo_stroke(cr);
//---------------------
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0, 1, 0, 1);
cairo_set_dash(cr,dashed1, 1, 0 );
cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1.5);

cairo_move_to(cr, 0, (j/2)+(sin( (-i/2)*sc   )*(h/2))  );
for(double x=(-i/2);x<=(i/2);x=x+10)
{
y=x*sc;
cairo_line_to(cr,x+(i/2),(j/2)+(sin(y)*(h/2))       );
}
cairo_stroke(cr);
//---------------------
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
cairo_set_dash(cr,dashed3, 1, 0 );
cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1.0);
cairo_move_to(cr,0,(j/2));
cairo_line_to(cr,i,(j/2));
cairo_move_to(cr,(i/2),0);
cairo_line_to(cr,(i/2),j);
cairo_stroke(cr);

cairo_destroy(cr);
return TRUE;
}
//*******************************************************************************
//*******************************************************************************
//*******************************************************************************
//*******************************************************************************

static gboolean invalidate_drawing1(gpointer data)
{
GdkWindow *win;

g_print("T_Signal-1 | amp1 = %2.3f   |   ",amp1);
if (toggle_stat1==true)
{
if ((flag_amp1==TRUE)&&(amp1 <= 3))
    amp1=amp1+0.25;
else
    flag_amp1=FALSE;
if ((flag_amp1==FALSE)&&(amp1 >= 1.25))
    amp1=amp1-0.25;
else
    flag_amp1=TRUE;
}
//---------------------

win = gtk_widget_get_window(GTK_WIDGET(data));
if (win) {
    GtkAllocation allocation;
    gtk_widget_get_allocation(GTK_WIDGET(data), &allocation);
    gdk_window_invalidate_rect(win, &allocation, FALSE);
}
if (flag_amp1 == TRUE)
    return TRUE;
else
    return FALSE;
  }
//**********************
//**********************
//**********************
static gboolean invalidate_drawing2(gpointer data)
{
GdkWindow *win;

//---------------------
g_print("T_Signal-2 | amp2 = %2.3f\n",amp2);
if (toggle_stat2==true)
{
if ((flag_amp2==TRUE)&&(amp2 <= 3))
    amp2=amp2+0.25;
else
    flag_amp2=FALSE;
if ((flag_amp2==FALSE)&&(amp2 >= 1.25))
    amp2=amp2-0.25;
else
    flag_amp2=TRUE;
}
//---------------------
win = gtk_widget_get_window(GTK_WIDGET(data));
if (win) {
    GtkAllocation allocation;
    gtk_widget_get_allocation(GTK_WIDGET(data), &allocation);
    gdk_window_invalidate_rect(win, &allocation, FALSE);
}
if (flag_amp2 == TRUE)
    return TRUE;
else
    return FALSE;
 }
//**********************
//**********************
//**********************
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
GtkBuilder      *builder;

GtkWidget       *togglebutton1;
GtkWidget       *togglebutton2;
GtkWidget       *togglebutton3;

GtkWidget       *button1; // Amp+
GtkWidget       *button2; // Amp-

gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

builder = gtk_builder_new ();
gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "GTK_Glade_2DrawArea01-R00.glade", NULL);                        //Carrega as informações do projeto glade para o GtkBuilder
window          = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window1"));          //Retorna o objeto Window, para mostrá-lo mais tarde
darea1          = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "drawingarea1"));      //Retorna o objeto DrawingArea, para mostrá-lo mais tarde
darea2          = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "drawingarea2"));      //Retorna o objeto DrawingArea, para mostrá-lo mais tarde
togglebutton1   = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "togglebutton1"));    //Retorna o objeto togglebutton1, para mostrá-lo mais tarde
togglebutton2   = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "togglebutton2"));    //Retorna o objeto togglebutton1, para mostrá-lo mais tarde
togglebutton3   = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "togglebutton3"));    //Retorna o objeto togglebutton1, para mostrá-lo mais tarde
button1         = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "button1"));          //Retorna o objeto button1, para mostrá-lo mais tarde
button2         = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "button2"));          //Retorna o objeto button2, para mostrá-lo mais tarde

gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK 2 Viewports DrawArea 01");

gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);    //Conecta todos os eventos dentro do projeto do glade.
g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder));            //Exclui o GtkBuilder, pois não iremos mais usá-lo nesse exemplo.

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(togglebutton1)  , "toggled"        , G_CALLBACK(on_toggled1)     ,   NULL);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(togglebutton2)  , "toggled"        , G_CALLBACK(on_toggled2)     ,   NULL);

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea1), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(draw_darea1), NULL);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea2), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(draw_darea2), NULL);

g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window) , "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit)  , G_OBJECT(window));

gtk_widget_show_all(window);   //Mostra a janela com seus objetos
gtk_main ();

return 0;
}
```

[image]

Here's the code fixed (below) after the suggestion andlabs and wogsland. Thank you.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <cairo.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    GtkWidget       *window;
    GtkWidget       *darea1;
    GtkWidget       *darea2;

    bool toggle_stat1 = false;
    bool toggle_stat2 = false;

    double fase1 = 2;
    double amp1  = 1.25;
    double fase2 = 4;
    double amp2  = 1.25;

    gboolean flag_amp1 = TRUE;
    gboolean flag_amp2 = TRUE;

//*******************************************************************************
static gboolean  on_toggled1(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
 {
    if(gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(widget)))
        {toggle_stat1 = true;
        printf("ToggleButton01 --> Acionado / toggle_stat1 = %d\n",toggle_stat1);
        }
    else
        {toggle_stat1 = false;
        printf("ToggleButton01 --> Liberado / toggle_stat1 = %d\n",toggle_stat1);
        }
return FALSE;
 }
//*******************************************************************************
static gboolean  on_toggled2(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
 {
    if(gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(widget)))
        {toggle_stat2 = true;
        printf("ToggleButton02 --> Acionado / toggle_stat2 = %d\n",toggle_stat2);
        }
    else
        {toggle_stat2 = false;
        printf("ToggleButton02 --> Liberado / toggle_stat2 = %d\n",toggle_stat2);
        }
return FALSE;
 }
//*******************************************************************************
//*******************************************************************************
static gboolean draw_darea1(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
  static const double dashed1[] = {4.0, 21.0, 2.0};

    cr = gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window(widget));
    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 1);
    cairo_rectangle(cr,0 , 0, widget->allocation.width, widget->allocation.height);
    cairo_fill(cr);

double i = widget->allocation.width;
double j = widget->allocation.height;
double sc = fase1*M_PI/i;
double y;
double h = 0;
if (amp1 != 0) h = h + j/amp1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 1, 1, 0, 1);
cairo_set_dash(cr,dashed1, 1, 0 );
cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1.5);

cairo_move_to(cr, 0, (j/2)+(sin( (-i/2)*sc   )*(h/2))  );
for(double x=(-i/2);x<=(i/2);x=x+10)
{
y=x*sc;
cairo_line_to(cr,x+(i/2),(j/2)+(sin(y)*(h/2))       );
}
cairo_stroke(cr);
     return TRUE;
 }
//*******************************************************************************
//*******************************************************************************
static gboolean draw_darea2(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
  static const double dashed1[] = {4.0, 21.0, 2.0};

    cr = gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window(widget));
    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 1);
    cairo_rectangle(cr,0 , 0, widget->allocation.width, widget->allocation.height);
    cairo_fill(cr);

double i = widget->allocation.width;
double j = widget->allocation.height;
double sc = fase2*M_PI/i;
double y;
double h = 0;
if (amp2 != 0) h = h + j/amp2;
//---------------------
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0, 1, 0, 1);
cairo_set_dash(cr,dashed1, 1, 0 );
cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1.5);

cairo_move_to(cr, 0, (j/2)+(sin( (-i/2)*sc   )*(h/2))  );
for(double x=(-i/2);x<=(i/2);x=x+10)
{
y=x*sc;
cairo_line_to(cr,x+(i/2),(j/2)+(sin(y)*(h/2))       );
}
cairo_stroke(cr);
     return TRUE;
 }
//*******************************************************************************
//*******************************************************************************
static gboolean invalidate_drawing1(GtkWidget *widget)
  {
        g_print("T_Signal-1 | amp1 = %2.3f   |   ",amp1);
    if (toggle_stat1==true)
        {
            if ((flag_amp1==TRUE)&&(amp1 <= 3))
                amp1=amp1+0.25;
            else
                flag_amp1=FALSE;
            if ((flag_amp1==FALSE)&&(amp1 >= 1.25))
                amp1=amp1-0.25;
            else
                flag_amp1=TRUE;
        }
        //---------------------
        gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);

        return TRUE;
  }
//**********************
//**********************
static gboolean invalidate_drawing2(GtkWidget *widget)
  {
            g_print("T_Signal-2 | amp2 = %2.3f\n",amp2);
        if (toggle_stat2==true)
        {
                if ((flag_amp2==TRUE)&&(amp2 <= 3))
                    amp2=amp2+0.25;
                else
                    flag_amp2=FALSE;
                if ((flag_amp2==FALSE)&&(amp2 >= 1.25))
                    amp2=amp2-0.25;
                else
                    flag_amp2=TRUE;
        }
        //---------------------
        gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
        return TRUE;
  }
//**********************
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder;
    GtkWidget       *togglebutton1;
    GtkWidget       *togglebutton2;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "GTK_Glade_2DrawArea01-R00.glade", NULL);                        //Carrega as informações do projeto glade para o GtkBuilder
    window          = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window1"));          //Retorna o objeto Window, para mostrá-lo mais tarde
    darea1          = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "drawingarea1"));      //Retorna o objeto DrawingArea, para mostrá-lo mais tarde
    darea2          = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "drawingarea2"));      //Retorna o objeto DrawingArea, para mostrá-lo mais tarde
    togglebutton1   = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "togglebutton1"));    //Retorna o objeto togglebutton1, para mostrá-lo mais tarde
    togglebutton2   = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "togglebutton2"));    //Retorna o objeto togglebutton1, para mostrá-lo mais tarde

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK 2 Viewports DrawArea 01");

    gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);    //Conecta todos os eventos dentro do projeto do glade.
    g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder));            //Exclui o GtkBuilder, pois não iremos mais usá-lo nesse exemplo.

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(togglebutton1)  , "toggled"        , G_CALLBACK(on_toggled1)     ,   NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(togglebutton2)  , "toggled"        , G_CALLBACK(on_toggled2)     ,   NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea1), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(draw_darea1), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea2), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(draw_darea2), NULL);
    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window) , "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit)  , G_OBJECT(window));

        g_timeout_add_full(G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE,250,(GSourceFunc)invalidate_drawing1,(gpointer)darea1,NULL);  // Variação atualizada da linha acima :-)
        g_timeout_add_full(G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE,250,(GSourceFunc)invalidate_drawing2,(gpointer)darea2,NULL);  // Variação atualizada da linha acima :-)

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);   //Mostra a janela com seus objetos
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

And the Final Image.

[image]

Comment: Don't use `gdk_window_invalidate_rect()`. Use `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` and `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area()`.

Comment: Suggested Reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank for the advice. I just able to solved the problem with it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the tip. I only able to solve the problem with it. I would like to post the resulted code (more Minimal and Complete now). But looks like I can't able to do it just like a comment. Is there any other way to share my results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `gdk_window_invalidate_rect()`. Use `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` or `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area()`.